# Using jQuery plugins in Angular`s ng-view

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ng-view

I have a bootstrap theme with lots of jQuery plugins used within it.
However my project is based on Angular.

As a result I faced a situation, when inside html template from ng-view loaded by $ngRoute jQuery plugins related styles and animation doesnt work. All those plugins added in root html.
When I add custom.js and star-rating.js into template.html everything works fine. But as far as I know it is not the best solution.

Here is a sample code. Not a working one, but just to see the picture of what is going on.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body ng-app="App">

<div ng-view></div> <!-- template.html inserted here -->

<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/plugins/rating/star-rating.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/route-config.js"></script>

<!-- Controllers -->
<script src="js/main/MainController.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thus I have few questions:

1) What is the best way to make it work?

2) Is it fine to use jQuery + Angular if jQuery is used only for "look and feel"? or I will face more problems in future?

Thanks!

Comment: show your code pls

Comment: 2) it is fine to use both together, as long as you can maintain and change your code in future

Comment: look and feel-based jQuery plugins should be used in directives, nowhere else

Comment: Take a look at examples, for example I see you use the star rating: https://github.com/akempes/angular-rateit

Comment: Thanks for replies. @DonaldWu , edit the post with part of the html to shed more light on a problem.

Comment: @devqon Thats why I`m asking. I have a bootstrap theme with ~20 different jQuery plugins, and moving everything to directives will take a lot of effort...

Comment: That's correct, but because in 'the old way' jquery initializes its plugins on document ready for all elements at once. Angular on the other hand (should!!) initializes the plugins per-element when it is/can be loaded/created after the document ready. Luckily for you, a lot of angular plugins already exist

Comment: @devqon Clear. Thanks a lot! Will go that direction